# What does amixer cset numid=3 3 do?

Tags: audio, hdmi, alsa, pi-4

In order to solve missing audio via HDMI with Raspberry Pi 4B (Raspian Buster) I came across

```
amixer cset numid=3 2
```

which didn't do the trick for me. But randomly I checked numbers from 0 to 4 and found that with 3 it works:

```
$ amixer cset numid=3 3
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
  ; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=3,step=0
  : values=3
```

According to [Raspberry Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/audio-config.md) options being only 0-automatic, 1-analogue (headphone jack) and 2-HDMI. No option 3. Trying with 4, keeps the previous setting, so I assume the allowed range is 0 to 3 (which is referred by the min and max bits in the output).

I tried `amixer --help` to find, if any changes were made recently to amixer, but couldn't find the information. In a very old [blog post](http://blog.scphillips.com/posts/2013/01/sound-configuration-on-raspberry-pi-with-alsa/) from 2013 the `numid=3` refers to 'PCM Playback Volume', whereas now it refers to 'PCM Playback Route' (`amixer controls`), so a change must have occured since then.

For RPi 4B:

```
$ amixer contents
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=3,step=0
: values=3
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Switch'
; type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1
: values=on
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'
; type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=-10239,max=400,step=0
: values=-23
| dBscale-min=-102.39dB,step=0.01dB,mute=1
numid=5,iface=PCM,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'
; type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1
: values=[AES0=0x02 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
numid=4,iface=PCM,name='IEC958 Playback Default'
; type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1
: values=[AES0=0x00 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00]
```

Whereas for a For RPi 2B the following is different (min to max is 0 to 2 only):

```
$amixer contents
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Route'
; type=INTEGER,access=rw------,values=1,min=0,max=2,step=0
: values=0
[...]
```

**It seems a change was made to PCM Playback Route somewhere between RPi 2B and 4B. I wonder what 3 is for and why it did solve the missing HDMI audio output issue. Any ideas?**

Comment: Please show the output of `amixer contents`.

Comment: While surfing for this answer I found something in this link https://sourceforge.net/p/picoreplayer/tickets/1/ you should check this.

Comment: @SohanArafat Are you referring to the issue with the changed onboard sound card number? No USB card plugged in, in my case. If I read this correctly sound card number is 0: `$ cat /proc/asound/modules` yields `0 snd_bcm2835`. Also I didn't get any error messages, when setting options 0 to 4 (not even with 4, which is not defined). I'm stuck here, since I don't have any USB card to play around with.